# Are my samples not independent?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, feature-selection

I want to predict soccer games and want to calculate the statistical significance of my features for selection. One of my features is the amount of points both teams have before the game.
Does this mean some of my samples are dependent?
As the amount of points for one game is dependent on the win/draw/loss of a prior game during the season:

example:
**team0_v_team1**

- label: hometeam_win
- points_hometeam: 12
- ...
- points_awayteam: 3
- ...

another sample:
**team0_v_team2**

- label: draw
- points_hometeam: 6
- ...
- points_awayteam: 7
- ...

Of course not all samples are dependent as there are lots of teams and many seasons (where the dependency would get "resetted" as they start with zero points again right?)

But this means I couldn't do a normal T-test for this dataset? Whar are my options?

Comment: Could you explain why you think a t-test might have some bearing on the predictive accuracy of your procedure?  The two are usually not related.

Comment: As I have a lot of features I want to get an overview of the statistical significances of the difference between groups for each feature. I want to try running the model with less features. Removing unnesecary features should be beneficial to my model right?